# Unable to run inkscape in PHP shell_exec() command

Tags: php, linux, shell-exec, inkscape

I have a [design tool extension](http://www.designnbuy.com/all-in-one-designer-html5.html) that is used on a website I'm working on. The design tool uses [inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/linux/) command line to export images. There is a php interface to work with the command line operations which ultimately calls `shell_exec($inkscapeCmd)`. After noticing the image files weren't being exported, I created a few tests to try and debug. I changed the execute line to `shell_exec($inkscapeCmd . ' 2>&1')` in order to see the error message:

`sh: inkscape: command not found`

...which is odd since it's definitely installed and accessible. I added a check for the user on my test page to make sure the commands were being executed by a user with access to inkscape:

`$processUser = posix_getpwuid(posix_geteuid());
echo 'user: ' . $processUser['name'];`

Then I ssh'd into the server to confirm that I could run the same commands as that user, and was able to run them without any issues (which also confirmed inkscape was in the PATH). I'm able to run other, basic shell commands from PHP without issue, like so:

`echo shell_exec('ls');`

But now I'm at a loss; I'm not sure what else to check to determine why I'm getting the 'command not found' error. Any direction would be helpful.

The server (rather old, I know):

- CentOS 6.7
- PHP 5.3.3
- Inkscape v0.47

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I thought I asked a reasonable question and I ultimately got the answer I was looking for; the design tool needed the path to the executable (it was defined incorrectly in a config file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process does not have the location for inkscape in it's path.

You will have to supply to full path to the executable.

Example

/usr/bin/inkscape

At the command line type 'whereis inkscape' to find is location.

Comment: That did it. Any chance you can explain why the process needs the full path in this case? Does it not use the process user's path?

Comment: The user that you are log into with is not the same user that the web server is running with. do an 'echo $PATH' on the command line. This will show your path. You can run executables with out having to specify the full program path. The user that the web server is running under more than likely is striped down to the bare minimum. That why if you look at a lot of web based soft ware you need to fill in paths for certain system software.

Comment: Previously, I did log in as the web server user when I tested from the command line. Is there some sort of modified settings/path when the web server is the initiator? Not sure if that's even the right way to ask that question?

Comment: You going to have to get into the depths of CentOS and assuming apache. To understand what is going on. I'm sure there are lot things going on to secure the web server. I myself just like to fill in the full path in a config file. One side benefit is of you need to have a different version of what is on the main distribution you can have it located in a different spot for you to access.